# ls on grub rescue - unknown filesystem

Tags: grub2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to fix "error: unknown filesystem. grub rescue>](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142300/how-to-fix-error-unknown-filesystem-grub-rescue)

My Ubuntu 10.10 system suddenly froze/crashed for no reason and I had to hard reboot my computer. Surprisingly it doesn't load anymore and stay stuck on a *grub rescue* prompt after an "unknown filesystem" message. That was enough clues to start googling for solutions.

a simple `grub rescue > ls` show me all partitions on hard drives :

```
(hd0) (hd0,5) (hd0,1) (hd1) (hd1,1) (hd1,2) (fd0)
```

According to all answers that I've already found, next logical step is to ls again the specific partition that contains the kernel, which is (hd0,1) in my case :

```
grub rescue > ls (hd0,1)
unknown filesystem
```

So here's **the problem : I can do a normal *ls*, but not *ls* a partition** (I tried all of them, just to be sure)

Other (unrelated?) issue, I can't repair anything since all Linux Live CD i try stay stuck in an infinite loading splash screen. The one with small dots below ubuntu logo.

Answer (score 4):

The "normal" **ls** that you are doing is running against the crash recovery pseudo-disk stored in `initramfs*`. The initramfs contains only enough tools to fix the system.

You may find this [how to mess with grub rescue](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1195275) article helpful, particularly section "17 Grub Rescue Image".

Does adding a slash:

```
grub rescue > ls (hd0,1)/
```

work?