# grub rescue -> no such partition

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, bios, grubrescue

I have a big problem with my computer...

I have reduced the windows partition and when I reboot then I have the grub rescue with the error message: "*no such partition*".

Moreover, I don't have access to the bios and so it seems impossible to change the boot sequence to boot on my live usb or live cd.

The command line `ls` gives me:
`(hd0) (hd0,1) (hd0,2) (hd0,3)`

I have a recovery windows partition (1 I think), a windows partition and a linux partition.

Yet, the command lines `ls (hd0,1)`, `ls (hd0,2)` and `(hd0,3)` gives me the error message: "*unknown filesystem*" and so I can't set a boot anymore.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Do you have Windows 8?

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/493826/grub-rescue-problem-after-deleting-ubuntu-partition/495993#495993) answer ...

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/493826/grub-rescue-problem-after-deleting-ubuntu-partition/495993#495993

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/493826/grub-rescue-problem-after-deleting-ubuntu-partition/495993#495993

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/493774/grub-rescue-without-cd-error

Comment: Please help in the above questions as well . I am unable to locate the partition and am fed up by ubuntu.please help. see my questions above .Thanks.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/493611/grub-rescue-windows-8-ubuntu-dual-boot

Comment: why cant you access your bios it has nothing to do with grub

Comment: @Sudheer I dont know much i would greatly appreciate if you could help me fix this Thanks

Comment: can you access you bios setting

Comment: when i boot i get the grub rescue prompt

Comment: no key works just ls command works

Comment: Before grub screen when your computer logo comes you should see "esc for setup" like that

Comment: yes esc for start-up but pressing esc does nothing

Comment: To solve your problem you may need Ubuntu live usb/cd.

Comment: @Sudheer Without cd there are some ways i found I don't have any CDs

Comment: Could you look at the links I have commented above They describe the way I have tried

Comment: Does it say any other keys than esc. like F11

Comment: No it says esc only maybe but sure I will try again by F11 when I get to my pc

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/493826/grub-rescue-problem-after-deleting-ubuntu-partition?lq=1   This question gives the way I tried

Comment: @Rafad Nole where is your question link

Answer (score 11):

The `grub rescue>` prompt signifies that GRUB 2 has **failed to find the grub folder**, the grub.cfg file, and/or the associated modules. The rescue prompt is presented so the user can provide the path to the grub folder, load the necessary modules, and provide the proper boot commands.

A common reason for the `grub rescue>` prompt is an incorrect path to the grub folder. Reasons for the prompt also include a failure to update GRUB 2 after certain system or **partition operations**, improper designation of the grub folder location, missing linux or initrd.img symlinks in `/`, or a failed installation.

To successfully boot from the `grub rescue>` prompt:

1. The grub folder must exist and contain the necessary GRUB 2 files and modules.
2. The proper paths must be set via the `set prefix` command. **Many GRUB 2 commands will not work until the correct path is set**. If the path to the grub folder (normally `/boot/grub`) is not correct, an "unknown command" or "file not found" message is likely.
3. The necessary modules must be loaded. The kernel cannot be loaded until the 'linux' module is loaded.
4. A Linux kernel and initrd.img must be located and loaded.

**In your case the grub folder and grub.cfg is seems to be available but inaccessible because your OS's partition can't be mounted, as the corresponding module is not loaded or it was corrupted during resizing. For the module to load, your grub should be completely loaded or the prefix should be set.**

For that, do the following:

1. `set prefix=(hdX,Y)/boot/grub`
   Use the values determined earlier.
   Example: If the Ubuntu system is on sda5, enter:
   `set prefix=(hd0,5)/boot/grub`
   In your case it most probabily is `(hd0,3)`.
2. `set root=(hdX,Y)`
   Confirm the correct X,Y values and press enter.
   Example: If the Ubuntu system is on sda5, enter: `set root=(hd0,5)`
3. `insmod normal`: Load the normal module.
   If the module loads there will be no message.
   If the module fails to load, try the full path: `insmod (hdX,Y)/boot/grub/normal.mod`
4. `normal`: Transition to the normal GRUB 2 mode with increased functionality.
   If the module loads there will be no message.
   If the module loads, HELP, Tab completion and command recall using the UP/DN keys should be available.
5. `set`
   (Optional) Review the current settings.
6. `insmod linux`: Load the linux module. An error message usually means the path is incorrect.
7. `configfile /boot/grub/grub.cfg` . This should load your configuration file that allows to boot all OSs.

Comment: Use the values determined earlier.  in step 1, but can you please tell whats that command

Comment: I have to do this every time I boot. How can I fix this permanently?

Answer (score 3):

As stated [elsewhere](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17911/ls-on-grub-rescue-unknown-filesystem), the correct command is `ls (hd0,1)/`. Please try to see if that will list the contents of the file system.

**To load your system manually in grub**

If vmlinuz and initrd.img do not exist at (hd0,3)/, you have to specify their exact location to boot into linux. So, in grub (please adapt vmlinuz and kernel versions to your setup)>

```
set root=(hd0,3)
linux (hd0,3)/vmlinuz root=/dev/sda3 ro
```

or if (hd0,3)/vmlinuz does not exist:

```
linux (hd0,3)/boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32.25-generic root=/dev/sda3 ro
```

then

```
initrd (hd0,3)/boot/initrd.img
```

or if (hd0,3)/initrd.img does not exist:

```
initrd (hd0,3)/boot/initrd.img-2.6.33-25-generic 
boot
```

More info can be found [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1195275).

Comment: After you get it booted manually, Run Boot Repair to fix your Grub - Here's just one of the many sources regarding how to do this: http://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/

Comment: I get: Unknown command `linux'. With ls I do see that vmlinuz and initrd are on (hd0,msdos5)

Comment: @Bram please open a new question on that, it might be a different issue, or search for other more fitting questions here

Comment: In my hp 15-ac026tx 'Ubuntu 18.04's case, both the vmlinuz and initrd.img were present in root, but it was "(hd0,8)/" instead of (hd0,1)/ , it shows "(hd0,msdosY) where Y is 123..89 etc number, but I did not need to type full (hd0,mados8)/ , only (hd0,8)/ worked as well the full fledged one.