# Grub Rescue Without CD : Error

Tags: grub2

I deleted 2 partitions on my hard disk and now I am unable to boot my pc. I searched and found that it is possible to boot without a CD, but the method is not working for me because I can't find the partition with the /boot directory.Each -ls (hd0,x) command says unknown file system.(x=1,2,3) Please help.I am stuck for 7 hours now.

The method I was using is :

```
ls
(hd0) (hd0,msdos3) (hd0,msdos2) (hd0,msdos1) // Tried to locate /boot after this
set prefix=(hd0,x)/boot/grub
set root=(hd0,x)
set
ls /boot ---> says unknown filesystem in every case for each x value
```

--Rest steps abandoned

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/493826/grub-rescue-problem-after-deleting-ubuntu-partition/495993#495993) answer ...

Comment: tHANKS BUT i GET UNKNOWN FILESYSTEM error in each ls (hd0,1) ... command.

Comment: which partitions did you delete

Comment: two unnamed partitions ( green ) in the windows 8 disk manager terminal

Comment: first you should identify the two partitions you deleted because if you deleted the Ubuntu partition there is no point in using that method.

Comment: How did you delete the two partitions and what did you do next?  If you did not resize the other partitions on the same disk, you may still be able to recover them.

Comment: i had resized one partition before deleting the 2 partitions which were unnamed

Answer (score 1):

If the steps you've done always returned an "Unknown FileSystem" error, this only means that one of the two unnamed partitions is actually **your Ubuntu partition** ! *I assume the other partition was the swap ..* I suppose why they were unnamed under Windows, 
because they were formatted as **exFat**, the FileSystem used among linux systems .. And, since Windows can't recognize these FileSystems, it simply showed them unnamed, and probably warned you that they might be used by other systems .. I know that, because *I actually formatted my linux partitions **three times** that way !*

The only solutions I think would be most practical is to re-install Ubuntu, your software and some recovery software in case you stored some important files in your Ubuntu partition ..

Also, Green partitions in the windows disk manager refer to **Extended Partitions**, *I'm not sure what that's supposed to mean, but that's how most linux systems are assembled ..*