# GRUB rescue problem after deleting Ubuntu partition!

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-7, grubrescue

After I deleted my Ubuntu partition, I rebooted my computer and I only get a prompt:

```
grub rescue >
```

The command `ls` lists

```
(hd0) (hd0,msdos5) (hd0,msdos3) (hd0,msdos2) (hd0,msdos1) (hd1) (hd1,msdos1)
```

I check them one by one:

```
ls (hd0,msdos5)/
ls (hd0,msdos1)/
```

But I cannot find the right partition.

Comment: Do you have another linux installation on your computer?

Comment: No, just ubuntu 13.04, but dual with win 7

Comment: And when I tried rebooting by usb or dvd, it said " Error loading operating system"

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. Please define "right partition" Are you trying to recover a partition that you accidentally deleted?

Comment: I can't post an answer so I write my answer her: create a ubuntu bootable USB,  then launch ubuntu from the USB, launch ubuntu terminal and write 
`sudo apt-get install syslinux` ENTER and then `sudo dd if=/usr/lib/syslinux/mbr.bin of=/dev/sda`. To create a bootable USB : http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows, to launch ubuntu from the usb, press F11 or F12 when your computer boot (before windows start). To launch ubuntu terminal  Ctrl - Alt + T

Answer (score 118):

Try the following ..

```
grub rescue > ls
(hd0) (hd0,msdos5) (hd0,msdos3) (hd0,msdos2) (hd0,msdos1) (hd1) (hd1,msdos1)
grub rescue > ls (hd0,msdos1) # try to recognize which partition is this
grub rescue > ls (hd0,msdos2) # let's assume this is the linux partition
grub rescue > set root=(hd0,msdos2)
grub rescue > set prefix=(hd0,msdos2)/boot/grub # or wherever grub is installed
grub rescue > insmod normal # if this produced an error, reset root and prefix to something else ..
grub rescue > normal
```

For a permanent fix run the following after you successfully boot:

```
sudo update-grub
sudo grub-install /dev/sdX
```

where `/dev/sdX` is your boot drive.

Comment: grub rescue > ls (hd0,msdos1) # try to recognize which partition is this -----> I am getting error : Unknown filesystem in each of the three partitions I get listed by the ls Command.Please help.Thanks.

Comment: the ls commands should be like "ls (hd0,msdos1) /boot"

Comment: this worked for me as well! but next time when i restart the machine i had to issue the same commands again. how do i resolve that?

Comment: @KillBill: insmod inserts the normal module to kernel using the root and prefix variables that are responsible for configuring the boot operation. A solution I can think of is to use the enhanced version of insmod, [modprobe](http://linux.die.net/man/8/modprobe) and run: `modprobe normal` from your installation. I don't really expect this to work, just tell me what output you get.

Comment: thanks for the reply. but i fixed it by login in through a live USB and issuing 'update-grub' command

Comment: This works and I'm able to boot. But I face this problem every time I boot, and I have to repeat this.

How do I make this solution permanent?

Comment: @Jim See comment above

Comment: @AmrAyman I did run update-grub upon booting, but not from a live USB. That didn't fix the problem.

Comment: @Jim issue 'grub-install' after that.

Comment: Great instructions, got my system back up and running in a couple of minutes thanks!

Comment: @AmrAyman, after I tried those 2 last commands, no success. I have to repeat every time. Do you have idea?

Comment: Yes. Look [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#via_the_LiveCD_terminal).

Comment: Fantastic! It works. One helpful thing would be that you can type ls (hd0,msdos1)/ (the trailing slash is important) in order to actually show you the files on the drive.

Comment: I tries 'ls (hd0,msdos1) /boot' for all. it shows 'unknown filesystem'. what should I do? Please help

Comment: On the machine I try to rescue, I find `(hd0,msdos1)/grub/grub.cfg`, accordingly `set root=(hd0,msdos1)` and `set prefix=(hd0,msdos1)/grub` but `insmod normal` only gives me an `error: file not found.`. What gives?

Comment: Worked exactly as described on a dual boot PC with Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 7 after removing an empty partition, thanks a million! NB: for finding the boot drive, see https://askubuntu.com/a/542360/438017

Answer (score 39):

To remove GRUB just download Windows 8 or 10 from another PC. Burn the iso into the USB with Rufus. Boot from USB, click **Troubleshooting**, then **Command Prompt**, and type:

```
Bootrec /fixmbr
```

Windows will start normally without Ubuntu's GRUB. You can reinstall Ubuntu again.

Comment: I run the command without the dot at the end:`Bootrec /fixmbr`

Comment: I had the same problem and after a day of searching and trying I think this is the best solution in this case. I have win 10 (UEFI) which works normally. I want to remove grub resuce from my legacy bios and install a new Ubuntu there. However, my laptop does not have CD-ROM. I had created a bootable USB for Ubuntu that worked perfectely for me before. But now the grub rescue refuses to acknowlege it and says uknown filesystem for all the partitions (including the inserted USB). I believe I would have the same problem with bootable USB for windows. So how can I get rid of grub rescue?

Comment: It seems that you are not booting from USB correctly! Select your usb from BIOS settings before grub appear!

Comment: Can I legally install Windows 7 this way? I have Windows 7 recovery partition and I am both unable and uninterested in installing Windows 8 on that computer.

Comment: It's very important circa 2020 to recognize that `fixmbr` commands will restore an MBR style boot. If you had UEFI before, it would now be MBR again. I don't see many correct answers floating around, so if you've already fallen into that place, you should look into Windows' `mbr2gpt` program which is part of the [WinPE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/winpe-intro) bootable. It's an absolute *PAIN* to use, but it works to get your disk back to GPT/UEFI. It possibly also has repair tools to restore a UEFI setup supposing you didn't run `fixmbr`.

Comment: Boot from USB -> "Repair Windows" instead of "Install Windows", then "Trouble Shooting".

Answer (score 6):

Boot your computer on a Ubuntu live-CD or live-USB

then follow the section **2nd option : install Boot-Repair in Ubuntu** from this link:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: I tried this. It claimed to have repaired it, but it just keeps putting me back to a grub terminal.

Comment: I tried boot-repair and still got black screen. In my case the problem was boot-repair attempted to repair my SD-card on laptop (based on log). So I removed the card from PC and re-ran boot-repair, then the boot was repaired.

Answer (score 2):

I did the same thing. Deleted Ubuntu partition. I am able to enter into BIOS.

If you have a bootable USB for Ubuntu, enter BIOS and choose the USB first in boot sequence. Restart. Then install Ubuntu again. And you can delete SAFELY this time.