# grub rescue at every boot

Tags: grubrescue

I had a dual boot installation (Win8 & Ubuntu). I was not using Windows much and decided to have Ubuntu for the whole system. When I reinstalled Ubuntu, I got the error

```
error: no such partition
Entering rescue mode
grub rescue >
```

Then I tried the following at the grub rescue

```
set root=(hd1,1)
set prefix(hd1,1)/boot/grub
insmod normal
normal
```

When I tried these command, I got the Ubuntu boot menu where I was able to start the system. However, when I shut down the system and restarted I got the same grub rescue error. Can you please help?

I am not sure if this helps. Here is the output of `sudo fdisk -l`

[image]

Comment: The question is five years old but OP signed on this year so surely the problem has been fixed by now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GRUB rescue problem after deleting Ubuntu partition!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/493826/grub-rescue-problem-after-deleting-ubuntu-partition)

Answer (score 0):

Those commands are fixing your problem temporarily.

Try running this command from terminal when Ubuntu is running to try to fix the problem -

```
sudo update-grub
```

Running just this command should be enough for you, but if it isn't, you can run all three of these to try fixing your problem. [Replace **X** with your drive letter]

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sdX
sudo grub-install --recheck /dev/sdX
sudo update-grub
```

Answer (score 0):

You must try Boot-Repair here : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair it easy use and have solved most problems about grup rescue

Comment: I tried that already. It did not work :(

Comment: oh :O okkay maybe you want to try another way like this, first step, check your ubuntu partition, ex: my ubuntu partition on /dev/sda2 and so go to command line and type :

creatorb@creatorb ~ $ sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt next type again creatorb@creatorb ~ $ sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt/ /dev/sda and last update your grub by type sudo update-grub and reboot

Answer (score 0):

if you just wanna boot into windows(btw i'm using windows 10) you can bellow method.
**step 1:** Go to your BIOS setup.
**step 2:** Go to boot device option or boot device order.
**step 3:** select os boot manager and press enter.
**step 4:** select windows boot manager and press f5.
**step 5:** press f10 to save.

It should change the priority of os boot manager to windows boot manager, and after rebooting your pc should boot into windows.