# how to get windows back on grub menu

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-7

I had wubi installed on my pc with Windows 7 and recently I removed wubi and the partition I had my wubi installed (I removed wubi because I had installed Ubuntu on a separate partition as a dual boot). This lead me to grub rescue problem. But I was able to resolve this my issuing the commands mentioned in the first answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/493826/grub-rescue-problem-after-deleting-ubuntu-partition).

This got me my windows and ubuntu on the grub back but had to re-issue the commands every time I restarted my machine. To get rid of this I used the [Boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) tool to fix it as was suggested on the web.

Now this had lead me to a situation where I have ubuntu but can't see the windows 7 on the grub list. Can someone please let me know how do I get it back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you update your grub ? If you don't , type

```
sudo update-grub
```