# unknown file system, grub rescue

Tags: 12.04, boot, grubrescue

I have a problem with my Ubuntu 12.04. I installed SVN on ubuntu. it worked fine  (I never shut down, as it was server). Last night Ubuntu crashed, and upon restarting, I got the following error:

`Error: No such partition`

Running `ls` command give me `(hd0)`

I ran commands mentioned in https://askubuntu.com/a/495993/489369, but it still giving me the same issue.

How can i fix it? Please, point me to the right direction. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Boot into a LiveCD and install and try Boot-repair-Disk. You will get loads of details abouts it If you google it :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is caused when the GRUB is damaged.

So my solution is:

Update the GRUB.

1. Have an installation disc of Ubuntu 12.04.
2. There boot from with this disc.
3. Then choose Rescue broken system.

That's all.