# Why Recurrent Grub Rescue Mode?

Tags: 14.04, boot, grub2, grubrescue

I am using the product *5.25" Tray-Less SATA Hot-Swap Hard for 3.5"HDD Hard Disk off / on Button* found [here](http://www.ebay.com/itm/5-25-Tray-Less-SATA-Hot-Swap-Hard-for-3-5-HDD-Hard-Disk-off-on-Button-/171488832614?) at the front of my Asus PC (2013 model) with Ubuntu 14.04.
I set successfully bios that you can boot from the hot-swap system.

However, I started to receive recurrent grub rescue errors after two month of use. I can fix the problem for one startup by pieces of instructions in the thread [Grub rescue problem after deleting Ubuntu partition](https://askubuntu.com/a/495993/25388) but it occurs after every shut down. Error at every startup

```
error: no such device: 48d470cc-7ad3-46e9-9646-622e16319f71
Entering rescue mode...
```

where I do the following which solves the thing only for one startup, after which the error comes again

```
grub rescue> ls
(hd0) (hd0,msdos5) (hd0,msdos1)
grub rescue> ls (hd0,msdos5)
(hd0,msdos5): Filesystem is unknown. 
grub rescue> ls (hd0,msdos1)
(hd0,msdos1): Filesystem is ext2. 
grub rescue> ls (hd0)
(hd0>: Filesystem is unknown. 
grub rescue> set root=(hd0,msdos1)
grub rescue> set prefix=(hd0,msdos1)/boot/grub
grub rescue> insmod normal
grub rescue> normal
```

The state of the OS may affect the recurrent grub rescue mode. 
I am receiving now many (2-3) internal errors from the system when keeping the system alive. I have received them few also before. 
I sent each time a report about the issue to developers with logs. 
However, no proceeding has happened with it.

---

How can you understand recurrent grub rescue mode in Ubuntu 14.04?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These instructions are for regular BIOS machines and are not for newer EFI machines.

Did you already run `sudo update-grub` after booting up Ubuntu? Running this command should update everything.

If not, you may need to reinstall grub to the MBR. Run the following command to do so:

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

Then, run `sudo update-grub` again for good measure.

Also, make sure grub is installing to the correct MBR on the correct disk. You can install grub to any MBR on any disk (even a USB drive) by altering the command above so keep that in mind.

Please post any errors.

Comment: No errors. It startups now without grub rescue mode. I will let you know if I see any internal errors and/or related errors later. Thank you for fast answer!