# Fixing grub rescue

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, grubrescue

I removed the ubuntu partition from windows and extended the volume to a existing windows partition. Earlier I had a dual boot windows and ubuntu. Now it shows me the grub rescue.

grub rescue>ls

```
(hd0) (hd0,msdos5) (hd0,msdos3) (hd0,msdos2) (hd0,msdos1)
```

I loaded a livecd of ubuntu and did boot repair. Still it is showing grub resue. And I don't have a windows cd.

After trying  doing a

```
"ls (hd0,msdos1) /boot"
```

on all of partition shown by ls[[1]](https://askubuntu.com/a/495993/417607). In each case, it shows Filesystem is unknown.

In the liveCD, I get this:

```
sudo fdisk -l
Device     Boot     Start        End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1            2048   31791103  31789056  15.2G 27 Hidden NTFS WinRE
/dev/sda2  *     31791104   32507903    716800   350M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3        32507904  780682991 748175088 356.8G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       780685310 1465147391 684462082 326.4G  f W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5       780685312 1465143607 684458296 326.4G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

I don't have any linux partition, should I install linux?
Is there anyway to fix this?

Gparted:
[image]

Comment: @Zacharee1 I tried  ls (hdX,msdosX)  \ boot on all partitions. All of them show  Filesystem is unknown.

Comment: I don't see that command in the answer there. Follow the procedure exactly.

Comment: @Zacharee1 I can't identify the partition. Please check question again, I have edited.

Comment: I think you need to burn a Windows install disc and use it.

Comment: @Zacharee1 Does it make sense to install linux from a liveCD and then try maybe?

Comment: Then you'll just be back with Ubuntu installed. If you remove it, you'll be back in this situation. Can you take a screenshot of what Gparted shows in the LiveCD?

Comment: @Zacharee1 okay. I have added a gparted screenshot. Please check.

Comment: @Zacharee1 To be clear, I removed the ubuntu partition from windows and extended the volume to a existing windows partition.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with MBR, but I think your only option is to get a Windows install medium and use its command prompt to fix boot.

Comment: Install EasyBCD on Windows and you can resolve your problem from there.

Comment: @ArijitChatterjee thanks for the suggestion! Can you provide more details. How can I do so  from the grub rescue? I am not able to boot into windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boot on Ubuntu with Ubuntu Live DVD/USB and execute`sudo fdisk -l`, note your hdd ID (sda in your case)

Now `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install syslinux`

Finally `sudo dd if=/usr/lib/syslinux/mbr/mbr.bin of=/dev/sda`

Exit and you can now reboot on Windows. Hope it helps, thanks

Comment: Thanks for answer! But I am getting this error while running it : `ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo dd if=/usr/lib/syslinux/mbr.bin of=/dev/sda`   
`dd: failed to open ‘/usr/lib/syslinux/mbr.bin’: No such file or directory`

Comment: Possibly a change in mbr location, try /usr/lib/syslinux/mbr/mbr.bin

Comment: Thanks so much! That works! If possible please provide some explanation. I have limited to no knowledge about mbr.

Comment: Dear Abhishek, I suggest you to read more on Google about it, as I am not an expert too. Regards