# Grub Rescue prompt appears after deleting Ubuntu partition. Can't boot Windows

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, bootloader, bios, grubrescue

I have an HP Pavilion dv 9543 cl. I decided that I wanted to update Win Vista to Win 8 several years ago, but did not know how to remove grub 2, so I naively decided to simply remove the Ubuntu partition and assumed I would be able to recover function of the Master Boot function. My shortsighted approach has left my laptop in limbo. When I attempt to start my computer it says:

```
error: no such partition
Entering rescue mode....
grub rescue>
```

I have tried the suggestion [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/493826/grub-rescue-problem-after-deleting-ubuntu-partition), however I am unable to enter the following command:

```
grub rescue > ls
(hd0) (hd0,msdos5) (hd0,msdos3) (hd0,msdos2) (hd0,msdos1) (hd1) (hd1,msdos1)
grub rescue > ls (hd0,msdos1) # try to recognize which partition is this
grub rescue > ls (hd0,msdos2) # let's assume this is the linux partition
grub rescue > set root=(hd0,msdos2)
grub rescue > set prefix=(hd0,msdos2)/boot/grub # or wherever grub is installed
grub rescue > insmod normal # if this produced an error, reset root and prefix to something else ..
grub rescue > normal
```

One question is where does the grub 2 remnant, which is interfering with the recovery of the original Disk 0 and 1 assignments, reside? Is it feasible to search and delete that code? Is there an alternative approach such as physical removal of the second hard drive (Disk 1 which became Disk 0)? Should the CMOS on the motherboard be replaced?

Comment: I edited out a bunch of your post because it wasn't relevant, and just wanted to clarify why: This issue is not related to the disk labels (C:, D:, A:, etc), nor is it related to the BIOS (well, it sort of is, but you certainly don't need to revert the BIOS to an earlier state).

Comment: Also, I'm not sure, but you seem confused about the differences between BIOS and bootloader. If so, see [here](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-the-BIOS-and-a-boot-loader/answer/Phillip-Remaker) for an explanation.

Comment: In my learning experiences (with the aid of the software on Hiren's Boot CD 15.2 {GRUB4DOS0.4.5C20121002 638k/2045M}, I found that the initial offering: Boot from Hard Drive (Windows Vista/7/2000 or XP) enabled me to start the notebook and to see the files on both hard drives. However, I am unable to start Windows Explorer and it seems as if the keyboard map is incorrect for the characters to the right of Y, H, and N; they become consecutive numbers or other characters

Comment: With the aid of Mini Windows XP (Hiren's BootCD), I was able to determine that the MBR (MBRCheck, ver 1.2.3) files on the \B: partition contain error 1; both Physical Drives 0 + 1 have unknown MBR; code:.

Comment: continued: SHA1: b36738553a8bea63b14a3f238b4d7d72ce018a64 for Phys Drive0;   SHA1: 77B257A4256C09D1F43929FABD9732372A5562EE for Phys Drive 1. Unfortunately, I attempted to correct those errors using the tools/instructions offered with no success.

Comment: I tried to figure out whether/how to use several other boot repair tools on the Hiren's  disk, but was similarly unsuccessful.

Comment: Where you are now able to avoid the Grub Rescue prompt on boot, this issue is no longer related to Ubuntu. You can refer to [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/) for assistance with Windows or other computer topics (BIOS, MBR, etc). If my answer helped you, please mark it as "accepted".

Answer (score 1):

You have deleted the Ubuntu partition, but the computer is still booting Grub, which cannot find the necessary boot files on the partition. You should change the boot options so that it boots Windows. Here's how:

1. Access your BIOS. This is sometimes done by tapping F12, F10, or ESC during boot. Look up instructions for your computer model if you're not sure.
2. Change the boot priority so that the Windows Boot Manager is at the top and Ubuntu at the bottom. Or just entirely remove Ubuntu as a boot option.

   - If the Windows Boot Manager is not present, and if I remember right, you will need a Windows repair/install disk to reinstall it, but ask over at a Windows support forum like [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) to be sure.

The computer should then boot Windows as it did before you installed Ubuntu.

Then once you can boot Windows you can remove all the traces of Ubuntu. See [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/133533/301745) for instructions.

Comment: I tried using a Windows Vista HP 32 bit disk to facilitate repair, however, that also failed. I thought about trying to reinstall the os using that disk's software, but am uncertain as to whether I would lose the information of that partition (original disk 1, partition c:) or whether the installation might result in installation on the former disk 1, now designated disk 0; pardon my naivety is my concern is silly.

Comment: Re restoring/resetting the BIOS on my 2007 model HP Pavilion dv 9543cl: The best info I have found on the HP.com site indicates that this model's BIOS should be accessed by simultaneously pressing the Windows and B keys when starting; there are supposed to be 8 beeps followed by a 40 second interval before the BIOS modification screen appears. When I try that procedure, there is one beep in second 1, two beeps in second 2, then in second 5 this process repeats for ever, though I stop after 5 minutes.