# Bios not working and cannot boot

Tags: boot, uefi, bios, gnu

I've got a problem after installing Ubuntu on an external drive with Windows 10 on my compute.

My bios is not working anymore and I have a blank page. 
After the bios, if I don't ask it, it goes on an Ubuntu gnu command line.
Something quite similar to this : https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=gnu+grub+version+2.02+boot&safe=off&rlz=1C1MSNA_enGB697GB697&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiambfhxL7NAhWmJ8AKHWV7ANwQ_AUICCgB&biw=1920&bih=955#imgrc=_4yFwpV7aJGGpM%3A

Can't understand what to do.

I do not care if i loose everything or whatever if my computer can work again.

Answer (score 0):

What seems to have happened is that GRUB (Ubuntu's default bootloader) has nuked the default Windows bootloader. I haven't used Windows in quite some time, but the solution is most likely to repair the bootloader using your installation CD.

There is some information on this blog post here - http://blog.d0zingcat.xyz/2015/09/28/Windows/How%20to%20repair%20the%20EFI%20Bootloader%20in%20Windows%2010/

Comment: I would have loved to but since my bios isn't working either I cannot do it..

Answer (score 0):

Ok this fixed everything : [GRUB rescue problem after deleting Ubuntu partition!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/493826/grub-rescue-problem-after-deleting-ubuntu-partition)

I did burn the ubuntu iso into an usb and did everything on it.