# Grub rescue without Linux

Tags: partitioning, grubrescue, ubuntu-mate

Initial state: dual boot laptop to either Windows 7 or Ubuntu.

What I tried to do: change my partition of Ubuntu to Ubuntu-Mate.

First problem: first booting for the installation worked fine, but I didn't create a partition with the free space obtained from the previous one.

What I tried to solve it: I restarted the computer and unplugged the usb in order to create the partition in Windows.

What really happened, and final problem: grub rescue is displayed, no matter what boot source used. (Edit 3: I wanted to gain access to my Windows partition, so that I could rearrange my partitions)

Thank you very much for any suggestion.

Edit: I've tried using a bootable Ubuntu usb to get the Boot-info, but it keeps giving an error: "unknown filesystem".

Edit2: I've tried via Boot-Repair-Disk, but even so it doesn't work, to   check whether the iso is correctly burned, I'll try it in another computer.

Comment: No idea what a "quit" is? Do you mean delete? But never use Windows tools on Linux partitions. And normally use Windows tools on NTFS partitions. Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Comment: Yep, I deleted the partition. I'll try the link tomorrow. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: I tried, but the same error occurs using a bootable USB.

Comment: You can [install MATE desktop](/q/87040/175814) in all flavours of Ubuntu without a complete system (re-)installation.

Comment: @DavidFoerster That would have been quite straightforward, indeed. Unluckily, the reason for the change was because I... Misused R files in that OS, so I needed a new one. Even so, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I used an [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/643528/650760) that I found that at least has given me the possibility to work with Windows. I'll continue working in order to get the new partition with Ubuntu-Mate.