# Can't boot to windows or Ubuntu! Please HELP

Tags: boot, windows

I am completely new to linux so please forgive me if i dont know much.

So I bought a new SSD 2 months ago. Did a clean install of windows 7 and then installed Ubuntu. Normally when I reboot it went to a screen asking what I wanted to boot and I could choose. I haven't even used Ubuntu much I've only booted into it 3 times so far. I primarily use windows and I just rebooted my computer and it goes to a black screen saying this

Error: No such device: 919a064-a8e0-4f26-a900
Entering rescue mode...
*****b rescue>

My computer is  connected to my TV so the left side is cut off a little so I can only see the letter b in the last line

What is this screen?? Am I screwed or is there any way to get back to windows from here. It allows me to type.

Please help I have no idea what this is!!

---

I've done a little research but still not sure what is going on. If I type "ls " the results are..

(hd0,msdos2)  (hd0,msdos1)  (hd1)  (hd1,msdos1)

I've then tried the following with each partition

ls (hd0,msdos2)/   but no matter which one I try I get "unknown filesystem

Is my new SSD dead already?

Comment: "Grub rescue" is probably what it says

Comment: Any ideas? Please help

Comment: Your boot device is not ready. Check hardware or boot sequence in BIOS.

Comment: Everything is normal in Bios.. My HD is showing there

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grub rescue problem after deleting Ubuntu partition!](http://askubuntu.com/questions/493826/grub-rescue-problem-after-deleting-ubuntu-partition)