# Laptop lost power during partition resize. Won’t boot and files unaccessable

Tags: boot, partitioning, data-recovery

I was resizing the partition (enlarging) with gparted when about 2 minutes in there was a power cut. Now it won’t boot up and the filesystem is unaccessable.

I can see the partition in gparted but on attempting to do anything it gets stuck on “checking file system”.

[image: gparted]

“Disks” doesn’t even recognise the file system - it just shows free space where the file system should be.

[image: disks]

When I click on the “173GB volume” in the launcher, it says “…structure needs cleaning”.

[image: launcher]

I’d appreciate if anyone can advise me how to get my data back. Please bear in mind I don’t have any USB drive large enough for copying the contents on the hard drive.

Comment: Check this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery testdisk can help you

Comment: Have you tried to check the filesystem on /dev/sda6 manually ? `sudo fsck /dev/sda1` in a terminal.

Answer (score 0):

[test disk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) is a powerful free data recovery tool that you can use to correct partition table and fix or recover data on disks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure in this case but you could try using fsck to check your filesystem consistency and try to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

"test disk" worked on a deep search.

Also needed to use the info here to boot up:

https://askubuntu.com/a/495993/773145