# How to resolve grub error?

Tags: grub2, grubrescue

I have just installed Ubuntu 20.04. Sometimes when I start up, it shows an error message in grub.  I then type the exit command.  Sometimes I have to repeat this process about 10 times before my laptop start.
How do I resolve this?

Comment: Put a screenshot of the error please. Also you dual booting?

Comment: Does it help [https://askubuntu.com/questions/493826/grub-rescue-problem-after-deleting-ubuntu-partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/493826/grub-rescue-problem-after-deleting-ubuntu-partition)?

Comment: If manually reinstalling grub as per above comment does not work. May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair