# error: no such partition Entering rescue mode. grub rescue

Tags: dual-boot

I am using Windows 8.1 and linux  as in dual boot. I have formatted drive  using disk management in Windows 8.1drive unknowingly--  Once I restarted the system, I am getting

error: no such partition
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue>

What to do now?

Comment: Similar questions: http://askubuntu.com/questions/491604/grub-rescue-no-such-partition http://askubuntu.com/questions/17911/ls-on-grub-rescue-unknown-filesystem

Comment: Nuts and bolts instructions you made need at http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/148041/recovering-from-grub-rescue-crash/148042#148042